# What is the right way to mock void functions in RhinoMocks?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have this interface that returns void in some functions that I would like to mock and wonder what is the correct way of doing so. As of now I have the following:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var mockedInterface = mocks.CreateMock<IMyInterface>();
Expect.Call(mockedInterface.FunctionThatReturn(param1, param2)).Return(Something);
mockedInterface.FunctionReturningVoid(param3, param4);
mocks.ReplayAll();

// Some assert and other stuff
mocks.VerifyAll();
```

Is that the right way of doing it? I think it looks weird since you're not handling the two functions the same way. What I would like to write is:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var mockedInterface = mocks.CreateMock<IMyInterface>();
Expect.Call(mockedInterface.FunctionThatReturn(param1, param2)).Return(Something);
Expect.Call(mockedInterface.FunctionReturningVoid(param3, param4)); // This doesn't work.
mocks.ReplayAll();

// Some assert and other stuff
mocks.VerifyAll();
```

But that doesn't work on row 4. I found some blog that says you can use lambdas (or delegate) like

```
Expect.Call(() => mockedInterface.FunctionReturningVoid(param3, param4)); // This doesn't work.
```

But that doesn't seem to work either for me. Having the `Expect.Call` makes it easy to identify mocked functions and that is why I want it. The compile error I get is: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type".

So how should it be done?

**UPDATE:** Added compile error information.

Comment: Can you post IMyInterface too?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the AAA (arrange/act/assert) syntax instead of record/replay.  It's more straightforward and makes the tests easier to read.  What you'll want to do is:

```
// arrange
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyInterface>
mock.Expect(i => i.FunctionThatReturnSomething(param1, param2)).Return("hello");
mock.Expect(i => i.FunctionThatReturnVoid(param3, param4));
// set up other stuff for your code (like whatever code depends on IMyInterface)
var foo = new Foo(mock);

// act
foo.DoSomething();

// assert
mock.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: The question isn't about how you should write your unit test, the question was about how you should mock void functions. But except from that, don't you need the `ReplayAll` before you can use `VerifyAll`?

Comment: Totally missed that both you and lazyberezovsky wrote one more comment. I've updated the post with compiler error.

Comment: @Tomas - The third line of code Patrick provided displays how to mock void methods. As for calling "ReplayAll" - that is not necessary when using the AAA syntax.  Note that the VerifyAll you are calling is on the particular mocked object, not on an instance of MockRepository.

Answer (score 1):

For void methods I use anonymous delegates:

```
Expect.Call(delegate { mockedInterface.FunctionReturningVoid(param3, param4); })
```

BTW: I like Record-Playback syntax for replaying and verifying expectations
http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/(S(j2mgwqzgkqghrs55wp2cwi45))/Comparison+of+different+Rhino+Mocks+syntaxes.ashx

Comment: But that won't even compile for me... and I don't know why.

Comment: Totally missed that both you and Patrick Steele wrote one more comment. I've updated the post with compiler error.

Comment: Error says that you are trying to pass delegate but method expects object. Verify your code. Maybe you typed 
*Expect.On* instead of *Expect.Call*?

Comment: My code says: `Expect.Call(() => mockedInstance.InstanceCall(someObject)).Return(true);`

Comment: How 'FunctionReturningVoid' could return true?

Comment: Please, verify you code. Because example you provided in question should work.

Comment: Here is an example which compiles without problems: http://www.2shared.com/file/CmUKp4Nd/SampleTests.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to test void method in AAA pattern, I was also having trouble mocking void. However, in the past, I use the Record and Playback style, and that should work.

Example:

```
private MockRepository m_mocks = new MockRepository();
private IXGateManager xGateManager = m_mocks.DynamicMock<IXGateManager>();

using (m_mocks.Record())
{
    xGateManager.SendXGateMessage(null, null);
    LastCall.IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Once();
}

using (m_mocks.Playback())
{
    //... execute your test
}
```